# Erro ao converter String para int

Tags: android

Preciso converter `String urlImagem` para `int`, pois a imagem irá ser carregada em um *adapter* e só aceita `int`, ou existe alguma forma de fazer a conversão do `id` em `String`?

O código abaixo retorna o erro

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "http:.."

Porque o *cast* de `String` para `int` não pode ser feito.

No LogCat esse erro

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.json.JSONObject.optString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference`

Adapter

```
    package com.example.android.listadelivros;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class DadosLivrosAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DadosLivro> {

    public DadosLivrosAdapter(Context contexto, List<DadosLivro> informacoesLivros){
        super(contexto, 0 , informacoesLivros);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int posicao, View converteVisualizacao, ViewGroup parente) {

        View visualizacao = converteVisualizacao;
        if(visualizacao == null){
            visualizacao = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.dados_livros_lista,
                    parente, false);
        }

        DadosLivro listaLivros = getItem(posicao);

        TextView titulo = (TextView) visualizacao.findViewById(R.id.titulo);
        titulo.setText(listaLivros.getTitulo());

        TextView descricao = (TextView) visualizacao.findViewById(R.id.descricao);
        descricao.setText(listaLivros.getDescricao());

        TextView autor = (TextView) visualizacao.findViewById(R.id.autor);
        autor.setText(listaLivros.getAutor());

        ImageView imagem = (ImageView) visualizacao.findViewById(R.id.imagem);

        if(listaLivros.temImagem()){
            imagem.setImageResource(listaLivros.getImagem());
            imagem.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            imagem.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        return visualizacao;
    }
}
```

Requisição HTTP e conversão do JSON

```
package com.example.android.listadelivros;

import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public final class ConsultaRequisicao {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = ConsultaRequisicao.class.getSimpleName();

    private ConsultaRequisicao() {
    }

    public static List<DadosLivro> buscarDadosLivro(String pedidoUrl) {

        URL url = criarUrl(pedidoUrl);

        String jsonResposta = null;
        try {
            jsonResposta = fazerPedidoHttp(url);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Problemar ao criar um pedido HTTP.", e);
        }

        List<DadosLivro> livros = extrairDadosJson(jsonResposta);
        return livros;
    }

    private static URL criarUrl(String stringUrl) {
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(stringUrl);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Problema na contrução da URL.", e);
        }
        return url;
    }

    private static String fazerPedidoHttp(URL url) throws IOException {

        String jsonResposta = "";

        if (url == null) {
            return jsonResposta;
        }

        HttpURLConnection conexao = null;
        InputStream inputStream = null;

        try {
            conexao = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conexao.setReadTimeout(1000);
            conexao.setConnectTimeout(1500);
            conexao.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conexao.connect();

            if (conexao.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                inputStream = conexao.getInputStream();
                jsonResposta = converterInputStream(inputStream);
            } else {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Erro na resposta do código: " + conexao.getResponseCode());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Problemas ao recuperar o resultado dos livros - JSON " + e);
        } finally {
            if (conexao != null) {
                conexao.disconnect();
            }
            if (inputStream != null) {
                inputStream.close();
            }
        }
        return jsonResposta;
    }


    private static String converterInputStream(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder saida = new StringBuilder();

        if (inputStream != null) {
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            BufferedReader ler = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

            String linha = ler.readLine();
            while (linha != null) {
                saida.append(linha);
                linha = ler.readLine();
            }
        }
        return saida.toString();
    }

    private static List<DadosLivro> extrairDadosJson(String dadosLivrosJson) {

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(dadosLivrosJson)) {
            return null;
        }

        List<DadosLivro> informacoesLivro = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            JSONObject respostaJason = new JSONObject(dadosLivrosJson);
            JSONArray dadosLivroArray = respostaJason.optJSONArray("items");

            for (int i = 0; i < dadosLivroArray.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject livroAtual = dadosLivroArray.optJSONObject(i);
                JSONObject informacaoVolume = livroAtual.optJSONObject("volumeInfo");

                JSONObject imagem = informacaoVolume.optJSONObject("imageLinks");
                String urlImagem = imagem.optString("thumbnail");

                String titulo = informacaoVolume.optString("title");
                String descricao = informacaoVolume.optString("description");

                String autor;
                JSONArray listaAutor = informacaoVolume.optJSONArray("authors");
                if (listaAutor != null && listaAutor.length() > 0) {
                    autor = listaAutor.getString(0);
                } else {
                    autor = "Autor Desconhecido";
                }

                DadosLivro inforLivro = new DadosLivro(titulo, descricao, autor, urlImagem);
                informacoesLivro.add(inforLivro);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Problema ao analisar os resultados JSON", e);
        }
        return informacoesLivro;
    }
}
```

No adapter, a imaogem será carregada por um ImageView, obviamente, e o construtor da classe para img é int, por se tratar de ID do xml, mas na conversão do JSON a url vem como String, dando incompatibilidade de tipos.
A minha dúvida seria se existe como o componente do xml ser puxado como String ao inves de um ID int, ou se dá pra converter a URL JSON em int?
Tentei fazer a conversão do JSON, mas ele informa os erros acima.

Comment: Aline, não sei se é possível representar uma String base64 coded em Integer.
No entanto, parece que o urlImagem está nulo.
Seu teste ali urlImagem não está funcionando por que você não abriu chaves. `{`.
Você só pode usar o if da forma contraida (sem chaves) se a instrução for apenas de 1 linha.
Tenta assim:
`if(urlImagem != null) {
   //aqui dentro o try.
}`.
Tenho quase certeza que o urlImagem é nulo.

Comment: @AndrewRibeiro eu já havia feito dessa forma antes e o resultado foi o mesmo, debuguei e a `urlImagem` recebe  o valor do JSONObject, o problema deve ta na conversão mesmo :/

Comment: `" componente do xml ser puxado como String ao inves de um ID int"`, porque não usar javascript para ir ao nó onde o ID e já nao tera necessidade de converter nada. Ex:`x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title")[0];
y = x.childNodes[0]; `

Comment: Acredito que eu tenha que instalar o plugin do JS pra poder usar no Android Studio, seria muito trabalho, deve ter alguma classe que puxe a view da da img como String e nao como ID int, sei la

Comment: Experimente assim : `urlImagem.getText().toString();
        int result = Integer.parseInt(urlImagem);`

Comment: Erro :  `Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "http://books.google.com/books/content?..."`

Answer (score 1):

Aline,

o listaLivros.getImagem() retorna que tipo de objeto?

o ideal para carregar a imagem no imageView apartir de uma url é baixar a imagem e criar um bitmap

```
public static Bitmap loadBitmap(String url) {
Bitmap bitmap = null;
InputStream in = null;
BufferedOutputStream out = null;

try {
    in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(url).openStream(), IO_BUFFER_SIZE);

    final ByteArrayOutputStream dataStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    out = new BufferedOutputStream(dataStream, IO_BUFFER_SIZE);
    copy(in, out);
    out.flush();

    final byte[] data = dataStream.toByteArray();
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    //options.inSampleSize = 1;

    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length,options);
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Could not load Bitmap from: " + url);
} finally {
    closeStream(in);
    closeStream(out);
}

return bitmap;
}
```

Com o retorno deste metodo inserir na ImageView

```
Imageview.setImageBitmap(retornoDoMetodo)
```

Comment: estou usando o Picasso, uma forma mais correta de trazer a imagem URL direto para um ImageView, deu certo rs

Answer (score 0):

Olá, Aline.

Não vejo muito sentido no que você deseja fazer e solicito que seja colocado um exemplo do tal adapter citado, pois acredito que o problema esteja na forma com que está sendo usado o adapter e assim poderei ajudar melhor.

Você pode obviamente transformar um `int` para `String` e até pode transformar um número que esteja no formato `String` para `int`, como `"123"`. Mas não vejo como uma `String` URL possa ser transformada em `int`.

OBS: Tem um erro no seu código que é a falta de chaves no `If`. Acredito que você saiba, mas explicarei para caso não saiba. Se não for utilizado chaves no `If`, ele apenas exercerá a condição para a primeira expressão a seguir da sua declaração, no caso, seria apenas o trecho `try {`. Todo o restante do código abaixo está fora do que é chamado do **escopo** do `If`:

```
    imagemURL = Integer.parseInt(urlImagem);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Problema na url da imagem", e);
}
```

É uma boa prática sempre definir o escopo do `If`, ou seja, **é uma boa prática sempre usar chaves**, mesmo que você queria que o `If` seja realmente válido apenas para a primeira expressão a seguir.

Aguardo sua edição com o adapter!

Comment: editado, dá uma olhada lá please.